# how to save clusters

Tags: python, cluster-computing, dbscan

I made the following cluster through dbscan skelearn

[image]

My data is a numpy array:

```
array([[-0.22725194, -0.68548221],
       [ 0.01525107, -0.98825191],
       [-0.29117618, -0.69614647],
        ..., 
       [ 0.62125361, -0.79422623],
       [ 0.59627969, -0.82673572],
       [ 0.58919524, -1.04003462]])
```

I would like to add the two new clusters as variables to my data.  The code I used was:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

data3 = np.array(data3)

dbscan = DBSCAN(random_state=111, eps=0.3)


dbscan.fit(data3)

# visualization

from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(data3)
pca_2d = pca.transform(data3)
for i in range(0, pca_2d.shape[0]):
    if dbscan.labels_[i] == 0:
        c1 = plt.scatter(pca_2d[i,0],pca_2d[i,1],c='r',
    marker='+')


    elif dbscan.labels_[i] == 1:
        c2 = plt.scatter(pca_2d[i,0],pca_2d[i,1],c='g',
    marker='o')

    elif dbscan.labels_[i] == -1:
        c3 = plt.scatter(pca_2d[i,0],pca_2d[i,1],c='b',
    marker='*')

    plt.legend([c1, c2, c3], ['Cluster 1', 'Cluster 2',
        'Noise'])
plt.title('DBSCAN finds 2 clusters and noise')
plt.show()
```

How can I save them as a variable?  Is there a function to evaluate the quality of these clusters such as Silhoutte Coefficient?

Answer (score 0):

You already have them in a variable: `dbscan.labels_`, don't you?

Not that you should be able to do something like `pca_2d[dbscan.labels_==1,:]` to avoid having to draw them one point at a time.

Evaluation of density based clusters is not easy. I'm only aware of a single measure that even *claims* it can evaluate density based clustering (I haven't used it, though, so I cannot vouch it works).

Silhouette etc. are *not* applicable. They assume convex clusters, and fail on the classic Jain toy problem.

> Moulavi, D., Jaskowiak, P. A., Campello, R. J. G. B., Zimek, A., & Sander, J. (2014).
>  **Density-based clustering validation.**
>  In Proceedings of the 14th SIAM International Conference on Data Mining (SDM), Philadelphia, PA.